# CanJS table click event

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-control

I am writing an canJS application and so far successful in handling the click event for an html table. Using the following code.

```
 'table td click':function(el,event){
        console.log('clicked ',el.text());
     }
```

1. How to listen to only first column click for the table instead of whole td?
2. How to retrieve particular column's data from the td (el)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
'table td:nth-child(1) click'
```

Possible answer of 2nd question, first handle whole tr:

```
'table tr:nth-child(1) click':function(el,event){
    console.log(el.find('td').eq(0).html()); // gets first column
 }
```

Comment: Hey that is working. Also can you help me with 2nd question? Handling click for the complete row and retrieve only first column's data.

Comment: I know jquery solution for that, I'll write it, it may be helpful